# Alterar estilo da DIV de acordo com FORM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Possuo a seguinte aplicação para realizar o login

```
public ActionResult Logar(String Login, String Senha)
{
    var bdUsuario = ClientesAplicacaoConstrutor.ClientesAplicacaoEF();
    var usuario = bdUsuario.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Codigo == Login && x.Senha == Senha);

    if (usuario.Count() == 1)
    {
        var user = usuario.First();
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.ID.ToString(), false);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Todo o formulário está dentro de uma div ID formLogin.

Gostaria de adicionar a condição de login uma forma de mudar o display da div id `formLogin` e consecutivamente exibir um outro conteúdo após o usuário realizar seu login.

Como o Controller não consegu encontrar o ID do elemento div, tentei com `Panel` e `Literal` com a tag `runat="server"` mas mesmo assim não consegui localizar a minha div para assim, alterar as propriedades `CSS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua `View` você vai ter que usar um `if` assim:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //logado                  
}
else
{
    //não logado                   
}
```

***Obs:*** Lembrando que agora não tem as tag `runat="server"` por se tratar de *MVC* e não *WebForms*.